How to make geoserver recognize I implement a new datasource?
I am develop a geoserver datasource extension.
How can I make this extesnion take active???
I put the jar into the D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib ,
my jar is quite simple.
My code is here https://github.com/yuyang-ok/geoserver_extension_test
you can use mvn package to make a jar file
when construct a datasource extension,should this jar organized like some mysql implementation??

Is it the most important you should impl org.geotools.api.data.DataStoreFactorySpi?

did you restart GeoServer? How did you create your jar? did you follow https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/datastore/intro.html? what does the log file say is happening (hint increase the level to GeoTools developer)?

Is this a proper document a start a new datasource implementation?

Is it should a constuct a jar implememt some class ?

like META-INF.services.org.geotools.api.data.DataStoreFactorySpi
